# Jasper iReport - properties text only on last page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report with group details coming from database fields and I have the report in 3 languages.

Now, I want to show certain text ex: `$R{endtext}` which comes from my `.properties` file on the last page only.

What I already tried and what didn't work was:

- lastpagefooter
- summary
- trying to add a group over the whole report..in the xml

Comment: When you say they did not work what do you mean. Last Page footer should work. If you just place static text in the last page footer band does it work as expected? If you place `$R{endtext}` in a different band (maybe title or header) does it work. Did you set the ResourceBundle property in the report to the name of the bundle to look for?

Comment: And you might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9453484/3340) to a similar question.

Comment: Hi jschoen, the Lastpagefooter shows my $R{endtext}, so the access to the ressource bundles is fine. But my last page also shows all the other elements from the previous page of my report header,group, details,etc. I want to have only the $R{endtext} on the last page, nothing else.

Comment: In that case place it in the `Summary` band, and then under the report properties make sure `Summary on a new page` is checked`. Then you should be good to go. As an aside to your actual issue, you may want to try to be more clear when you ask questions. For instance, the way your current question reads it seems like the value from `$R{endText}` was not being retrieved correctly from your properties file. You just say it does not work. In the future try to be more specific. It will get you help faster.