# How to use a parameter in field description?

Tags: jasper-reports, locale

I have a report with a xml file as datasource, in the main file I have a line of code that looks like this (the value depends on the users preferences)

```
<property identifier="locale">en</property>
```

I save this as a parameter and pass it to my subreport since I can't seem access this line from my subreport (this line is in the root node of the xml document which my main.jrxml connects to, my subreport uses a subdatasource further down the document). In my subreports I have lines that looks like this:

```
<label language="sv"><![CDATA[Ledord]]></label>
<label language="en"><![CDATA[Guide word]]></label>
```

I'm trying to select the correct label to use in my report by using my locale parameter in the field description. Some examples of what I've tried without success:

```
label[@language='" + $P!{locale} + "']
label[@language='" + $P{locale} + "']
label[@language=$P!{locale}]
label[@language=$P{locale}]
```

I've tried it in the fields description. Here's that part of the jrxml:

```
<field name="head" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[label[@language='" + $P!{locale} + "']]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Is this possible to achieve or do I have to do it some other way?

Internationalization does not seem to solve my problem since it's for static text that I know beforehand will take place in my report. The XML is generated from user input and different parts may use different locales. So I can't add it to my localized messages.

Comment: As far as I know all JasperReport parameters, fields, variables are only accessible within an expression field, e.g. the text expression, a group expression, a print when expression or of course the main data select. So it would always be in a CDATA. Where do you use the `label`s?

Comment: I use them in a field to display the CDATA, like this: $F{label} but I'm unable to chose the correct one

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to know where this definition `label[@language=$P{locale}]` takes place. Please post a bit more of your jrxml regarding this context.

Comment: @Ivyen Maybe this help you to solve task: [Internationalized Report Templates](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n). Your question is unclear

Comment: @tobi6 I've tried it in the fields description. Here's that part of the jrxml:
<field name="head" class="java.lang.String">
<fieldDescription><![CDATA[label[@language='" + $P!{locale} + "']]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

Comment: @AlexK Thanks, I'll have a look at that. Yes it seems so, trying to clarify it the best I can.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and don't post code in the comments.

Comment: The information you asked for was already in the question hence the comment to point to the correct part.

Comment: The field code wasn't initially part of the question. I added it from your comment. I am not sure if the class `String` would be right for this since a string would always start with `"`. The way AlexK suggested seems more appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a multi language report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438246/how-to-create-a-multi-language-report)

Comment: There you have an answer from @AlexK on how to use property files