# Replace a string parameter within a CDATA parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

Given a textFieldExpression `![CDATA[$P{pageNumber}]]` such as `pageNumber="Page {0} from {1}"` which I do read from a `.properties` file, I would like to replace the parameters `{0}` and `{1}` with the report variables `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` and `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` respectively. How may I achieve that please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a multi language report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438246/how-to-create-a-multi-language-report)

Comment: You can skip the step with reading properties file and use this exression: `<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[msg($R{text.pageNumber}, $V{PAGE_NUMBER}, $V{PAGE_COUNT})]]></textFieldExpression>`. Description is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with pure Java:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.text.MessageFormat.format($P{pageNumber}, new Object[] {$V{PAGE_NUMBER},$V{PAGE_COUNT}})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

However, if you are trying to internationalise your report, you don't need to manually read your keys and populate parameters, you could just use, just as @AlexK mentioned, the built-in `resourceBundle` support by following the [JasperReports i18n Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html).